# Change column format to currency in ClosedXML.Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I create `System.Data.DataTable` and I put the data to an Excel using `ClosedXML.Excel`

```
System.Data.DataTable table = GetTable();
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Acompanhamento - Cultura");
ws.FirstCell().InsertTable(table, false);
var range = ws.RangeUsed();
```

Problem is that I have columns as string with values like $20000 or R$10000 (currency is changing) and I don't know how to set the currency type to these columns and not lose information about currency.

Thank You for help.

Comment: What is the data type of the applicable column in your `DataTable`? If it is a string, then it will be dumped into the ClosedXML worksheet as a string. You would need to loop through the cells in that column yourself, remove the currency symbols, parse the remaning value and set the cell format appropriately to display it as a currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the table I created, I add a column with currencyID, and column with only number, without information about currency, this table I added to an Excel, and later in loop I checked row by row what is currency Id and format the cell

```
   ws.Cell(j, i).Style.NumberFormat.Format = ws.Cell(j, i).Value.ToString() != "" ? Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(j, (i-1)).Value) == 2 ? " [$R$-pt-BR]#,##0.00" : "[$$-en-US] #,##0.00" : "";}
```

where `ws.Cell(j, i)` is cell with value (number) and `ws.Cell(j, (i-1))` is cell with currency id